# Why only string view?

Tags: c++

C++17's string view gives developers a way to pass around cheap non-owning references to a string that can actually be [faster than `const std::string&`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40127965/how-exactly-stdstring-view-is-faster-than-const-stdstring?rq=1). I might be naive, but this sounds pretty similar to Java's built-in mechanic to copy *references* of an object. Built-in wrappers like Integer and String are immutable. Java's "reference" mechanic gives you a guarantee that these objects will hold the same value throughout the lifetime of a program. The difference is in C++, `string_view` is explicit in a program like so:

```
void retrieve_an_object (string_view sv) {
}
```

This is more self-documenting than Java's surprising (to C++ developers) mechanic. But surely it is a huge burden to the standard and library writers to write a view class for every conceivable class in C++. Could C++ perhaps have a more dedicated way of marking objects as "view only" without having to write an entire class and if so, why has this been removed from consideration?

Comment: It isn't a view of a `std::string`, but a view of a contiguous sequence of characters. It has most of the the `std::string` interface because that's consistent.

Comment: `const type&` is the fastest way to provide a view only interface to a class. `string_view` is special because you use it when you *don't have* a `std::string`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why string\_view instead of generalized container\_view<T>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39034413/why-string-view-instead-of-generalized-container-viewt)

Answer (score 6):

The view classes (`string_view`, `array_view`) are meant to give (read only) access to *parts* of the object they are presenting.
It’s like a `const &` with additional information about a different beginning and end.

C++ has a dedicated way for view only objects: `const &`. (as well as `std::reference_wrapper<const T>`)

If you only want to give access to specific parts of some data structure you need a dedicated view class which knows what parts should be made available, this is not really generalizable per se.