# Why there is no view<T> similar to std::string_view

Tags: c++, c++17, stdstring

I am aware that `std::string_view` is **a non-owning reference to a string** and the major differences between `std::string_view` and `std::string` are

[image]

Now, Why std::string_view is not applicable to other types ? or  why this implementation is specific ONLY to `std::string` ?

For Example : if we have similar `<T>generic_view` where `T` can be of any type including custom types.

With this, instead of using `const T&`  as function argument, `<T>generic_view` can be used. And also other advantages of `std::string_view` will be useful like Allocation, Copying etc..

Comment: I forgot why it was not included but GSL to the rescue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45723819/what-is-a-span-and-when-should-i-use-one

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why string\_view instead of generalized container\_view<T>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39034413/why-string-view-instead-of-generalized-container-viewt)

Comment: How would `string_view<double>` work or `string_view<pair<int, double>>`?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There is a **non-owning** type for contiguous collections of arbitrary objects in C++20 called [`std::span`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/span).

Versions of C++ prior to C++20 can use the standalone implementation [`gsl::span`](https://github.com/Microsoft/GSL).

`std::span` behaves similarly to C++17's [`std::string_view`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string_view), but the interface provides *general* container-like access instead of string-like access, and the underlying data can be non-`const`.   (From the table in the question, **Element Mutability** is **Allowed**.)

Comment: Sweet, it made it in.

Comment: Just wondering what will be  the future of `std::string_view` ? Because one can easily use std::span for std::string.

Comment: `span` is not a "view"; views are non-modifiable; `span` is modifiable.

Comment: @Sitesh: "*Because one can easily use std::span for std::string.*" Unless you want to use the string-specific member functions of `string_view`.

Comment: @NicolBolas No, `span` is definitely a View. View does not imply non-modifiable.

Comment: Also, potentially mutable... you can have `span<T const>`, for instance...

Comment: @Sitesh We'll have `span<char const>` and `string_view` in the same way that today we have `vector<char>` and `string`.

Comment: Is it not good idea to create a view of any type T generically with immutability (just as string_view) ?

Comment: What I think we are saying is that std::span *is* a generic view for a linear container (c array std::array, std::vector, std::string). The "main/only" benefit that string_view gives you is the additional text-specific member functions such as find/rfind/substr, which make no sense on other containers.

Comment: @Sitesh That type is spelled `span<T const>`.